# Adding additional element from another namespace into xsl file

Tags: xml, xslt

We are trying to add in an additional element that uses another namespace within the stylesheet below:

This is used to pull data from an XML file into a rendered copy of an invoice.

The element uses the following namespace so I've added it in as an additional one:

```
xmlns:f="http://services.finance.com/schema/finbwSchemaLib/2005/05/13"
```

To add in the additional element called 'Vat Reg No', I have added in the div element:

```
<td width="25%">VATReg</td>
```

Then I added in the value of for the element within the template match section that corresponds to the additional namespace 'f':

```
<xsl:value-of select="f:VatRegNo"/>
```

However, when a XML invoice is pulled through the stylesheet does not pick up this value. The XML file contains VAT Reg No.

Is there something I am missing to add this additional element?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fin="http://services.finance.com/schema/finbwInvoice/2006/11/20" xmlns:finlib="http://services.finance.com/schema/finbwSchemaLib/2006/11/20" xmlns:f="http://services.finance.com/schema/finbwSchemaLib/2005/05/13"  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2004/10/xpath-functions" xmlns:xdt="http://www.w3.org/2004/10/xpath-datatypes">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <HTML>
            <head>
                <title>finance INVOICE</title>
                <style><![CDATA[
                TD {
                    VERTICAL-ALIGN: top;
                }

                .heading {
                    font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
                    font-size:14pt;
                    font-weight:bold;
                    margin-top:12pt;
                    margin-bottom:12pt;
                }

                .address {
                    font-size:10pt;
                    font-family:Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
                }

                .narrative {
                    font-style:italic;
                }

                .delivsched{
                    font-size:10pt;
                }
            ]]></style>
            </head>
            <body>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="//fin:finbwInvoice"/>
            </body>
        </HTML>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="fin:finbwInvoice">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="fin:Invoice"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="fin:Invoice">
        <div align="left">
            <!-- ================= -->
            <!-- INVOICE addresses -->
            <!-- ================= -->
            <table border="0" width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td width="32%" height="23" valign="top">
                        <b/>Invoice To:</td>
                    <td width="1%" height="150" valign="top" rowspan="2"/>
                    <td width="33%" height="23" valign="top">
                        <b/>Payment To:</td>
                    <td width="1%" height="150" valign="top" rowspan="2"/>
                    <td width="32%" height="23" valign="top">
                        <b/>Deliver To:</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td valign="top" bgcolor="#C0C0C0">
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="fin:Header/fin:BillTo"/>
                    </td>
                    <td valign="top" bgcolor="#C0C0C0">
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="fin:Header/fin:Seller"/>
                    </td>
                    <td valign="top" bgcolor="#C0C0C0">
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="fin:Header/fin:ShipTo"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <br/>
            <!-- ============================= -->
            <!-- INVOICE text -->
            <!-- ============================= -->
            <p>
            <td width="15%">Invoice Text: </td>
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="fin:Header/fin:InvoiceText"/>
                    </td>
            </p>
            <!-- ============================= -->
            <!-- INVOICE dates, references etc -->
            <!-- ============================= -->
            <table border="1" width="100%" height="68" bordercolor="black">
                <tr bgcolor="#000000" style="color:white;font-size:10pt;font-family:Tahoma;font-weight:bold">
                    <td width="15%">Date</td>
                    <td width="15%">Invoice number</td>
                    <td width="15%">PO number</td>
                    <td width="20%">Our Ref</td>
                    <td width="20%">Your Ref</td>
                    <td width="15%">Delivery Method</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="fin:Header/finlib:InvoiceDate"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="fin:InvoiceNo"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="fin:Header/fin:OrderRef"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="fin:Header/fin:Seller/fin:Contact"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="fin:Header/fin:Buyer/fin:Accountable"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="fin:Header/fin:DeliveryInfo/fin:DelivMethodDescr"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <br/>
            <!-- ============= -->
            <!-- INVOICE lines -->
            <!-- ============= -->
            <table border="0" width="100%" height="108" cellpadding="5">
                <tr bgcolor="#C0C0C0" style="font-size:10pt;font-family:Tahoma">
                    <td align="left">Article</td>
                    <td align="left">Description</td>
                    <td align="left">Unit</td>
                    <td align="right">Quantity</td>
                    <td align="right">Price</td>
                    <td align="right">Discount%</td>
                    <td align="right">Amount</td>
                </tr>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="fin:Details/fin:Detail"/>
            </table>
            <!-- =============== -->
            <!-- INVOICE tax details -->
            <!-- =============== -->
            <table border="0" width="50%" height="68" bordercolor="black">
                <tr bgcolor="#000000" style="color:white;font-size:10pt;font-family:Tahoma;font-weight:bold">
                    <td width="25%">Tax %</td>
                    <td width="25%">Total excl tax</td>
                    <td width="25%">Tax</td>
          <td width="25%">VATReg</td>
                </tr>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="fin:Details/fin:Detail/fin:TaxDetails"/>
            </table>
            <br/>
            <!-- ============= -->
            <!-- INVOICE total -->
            <!-- ============= -->
            <table border="0" width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td width="90%" align="right">Total excl tax</td>
                    <td width="10%" align="right">
                        <xsl:value-of select="fin:Summary/fin:TotalExclTax"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="right">Tax</td>
                    <td width="10%" align="right">
                        <xsl:value-of select="fin:Summary/fin:TotalTax"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="right">Total in <xsl:value-of select="fin:Header/fin:Currency"/>
                    </td>
                    <td width="10%" align="right">
                        <xsl:value-of select="fin:Summary/fin:TotalInclTax"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- "INVOICE" -->
    <xsl:template match="fin:Detail">
        <tr>
            <td align="left">
                <xsl:value-of select="fin:Products/fin:SellerProductCode"/>
            </td>
            <td align="left">
                <xsl:value-of select="fin:Products/fin:SellerProductDescr"/>
            </td>
            <td align="left">
                <xsl:value-of select="fin:Products/finlib:UnitCode"/>
            </td>
            <td align="right">
                <xsl:value-of select="fin:Products/finlib:Quantity"/>
            </td>
            <td align="right">
                <xsl:value-of select="fin:Products/fin:Price"/>
            </td>
            <td align="right">
                <xsl:value-of select="finlib:DiscountPct"/>
            </td>
            <td align="right">
                <xsl:value-of select="fin:LineTotExclTax"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="fin:TaxDetails">
        <tr>
            <td align="left">
                <xsl:value-of select="fin:TaxPercent"/>
            </td>
            <td align="right">
                <xsl:value-of select="fin:LineTotExclTax"/>
            </td>
            <td align="right">
                <xsl:value-of select="fin:TaxAmount"/>
            </td>
      <td align="right">
                <xsl:value-of select="f:VatRegNo"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="fin:Seller|fin:BillTo|fin:ShipTo">
        <SPAN class="finlibaddress">
            <DIV>
                <xsl:value-of select="finlib:Name"/>
            </DIV>
            <DIV>
                <xsl:value-of select="finlib:AddressInfo/finlib:Address"/>
            </DIV>
            <DIV>
                <xsl:value-of select="finlib:AddressInfo/finlib:ZipCode"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="finlib:AddressInfo/finlib:Place"/>
            </DIV>
            <DIV>
                <xsl:value-of select="finlib:AddressInfo/finlib:Country"/>
            </DIV>
        </SPAN>
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- "Address" -->
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is the XML file below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><finbwInvoice xmlns="http://services.fin.com/schema/finbwInvoice/2006/11/20" xmlns:finlib="http://services.fin.com/schema/finbwSchemaLib/2006/11/20" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://services.fin.com/schema/finbwInvoice/2006/11/20 http://services.fin.com/schema/finbwInvoice/2006/11/20/finbwInvoice.xsd">
  <Invoice>
    <InvoiceNo>Invoice_Number</InvoiceNo>
    <Header>
      <finlib:InvoiceDate>2016-08-22</finlib:InvoiceDate>
      <OrderRef>123456789</OrderRef>
      <OrderNo>0</OrderNo>
      <finlib:ContractId/>
      <ArchivePath/>
      <Currency>GBP</Currency>
      <Seller>
        <finlib:Name>Seller Name</finlib:Name>
        <finlib:AddressInfo>
          <finlib:Address>01 Address</finlib:Address>
          <finlib:Place>Place</finlib:Place>
          <finlib:Province>Province</finlib:Province>
          <finlib:ZipCode>AB1 2DC</finlib:ZipCode>
        </finlib:AddressInfo>
        <finlib:CompRegNo/>
        <finlib:VatRegNo>GB12345678</finlib:VatRegNo>
        <finlib:SellerNo>1234567</finlib:SellerNo>
      </Seller>
      <BillTo>
        <finlib:Name>Buyer Name</finlib:Name>
        <finlib:AddressInfo>
          <finlib:Address>02 Address</finlib:Address>
          <finlib:Place>Place</finlib:Place>
          <finlib:ZipCode>XY9 8UV</finlib:ZipCode>
        </finlib:AddressInfo>
      </BillTo>
      <finlib:ReferenceCode>
        <finlib:Code/>
        <finlib:Value/>
      </finlib:ReferenceCode>
    </Header>
    <Details>
      <Detail>
        <LineNo>2</LineNo>
        <finlib:TransDate>2016-08-22</finlib:TransDate>
        <LineTotExclTax>1000.00</LineTotExclTax>
        <TaxPercent>20.00</TaxPercent>
        <TaxAmount>212.80</TaxAmount>
        <LineTotInclTax>1276.80</LineTotInclTax>
        <finlib:TaxCode>V</finlib:TaxCode>
        <Products>
          <SellerProductCode>AAA1A222AD</SellerProductCode>
          <SellerProductDescr>Seller Product Description</SellerProductDescr>
          <finlib:UnitCode>UN</finlib:UnitCode>
          <finlib:Quantity>1.00</finlib:Quantity>
          <Price>1064.00</Price>
        </Products>
      </Detail>
      <Detail>
        <LineNo>1</LineNo>
        <finlib:TransDate>2016-08-22</finlib:TransDate>
        <LineTotExclTax>572.00</LineTotExclTax>
        <TaxPercent>20.00</TaxPercent>
        <TaxAmount>114.40</TaxAmount>
        <LineTotInclTax>686.40</LineTotInclTax>
        <finlib:TaxCode>V</finlib:TaxCode>
        <Products>
          <SellerProductCode>41415</SellerProductCode>
          <SellerProductDescr>Product Description</SellerProductDescr>
          <finlib:UnitCode>UN</finlib:UnitCode>
          <finlib:Quantity>1.00</finlib:Quantity>
          <Price>572.00</Price>
        </Products>
      </Detail>
    </Details>
    <Summary>
      <TotalExclTax>1636.00</TotalExclTax>
      <TotalTax>327.20</TotalTax>
      <TotalInclTax>1963.20</TotalInclTax>
    </Summary>
  </Invoice>
</finbwInvoice>
```

This is processed using the stylesheet to produce a rendered invoice html file with all the elements of the XML file.

Comment: Is it possible to attach input and output samples?

Comment: I don't see where `<xsl:value-of select="f:VatRegNo"/>` appears in your stylesheet. And I don't see your XML input, so I have way of telling how your stylesheet should retrieve that value from it.

Comment: sorry - i've amended it to show that value

Comment: Depending on your history, i highly doubt that you know, how to accept an answer. Please see this link http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work in case of need.

Answer (score 0):

**Wrong:** Element `VatRegNo` is not in your `f`-namespace!

In your source document the element (`VatRegNo`) is in namespace `http://services.fin.com/schema/finbwSchemaLib/2006/11/20`.

To select it, bind a prefix to that uri and call it.

In your rootnode add `xmlns:finlib="http://services.fin.com/schema/finbwSchemaLib/2006/11/20"` and you can call the element - respectly on your context node - via `finlib:VatRegNo`.